# Squid proxy : Is there a way to block source ports or only accept proxy requests from a specific port?

Tags: tcp, proxy, port, squid

I have a scenario where I need to allow access only from a specific source port. I know how to block access to a destination port, say for example for HTTPS:

```
acl SSL_ports port 443
http_access deny !Safe_ports
```

My understanding is that this will ensure that the destination port 443 alone will be serviced. But Im not able to see any case when a source port can be filtered. Is this possible at all?

Comment: I don't think this is possible in squid. It also usually makes no sense, since with TCP one cannot reuse the same source port for multiple connections from the same IP but multiple parallel connections are often used with HTTP. Even reusing the same source port quickly between consecutive connections is not possible in TCP. Therefore the OS will by default pick a random source port for a new connection.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich So, if I understand correctly, its impossible to determine which port the OS picks to make a connection and block the same with either a proxy or a firewall.

Comment: Yes, usually there is no way in applications to fix the used source port in TCP. And it would also not make sense in most use cases to provide a way. Specifying the source port in TCP has only very few and limited use cases.